# AngularJs - call $scope function on the onclick event from <img> tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new with JS and AngularJs. In my controller i have the following code:

```
      angular.forEach(resData, function(file) {
   $('.shelfgallery').append('<div class="responsive"><div class="gallery">' + '<img id="img' + fotoId + '" src="' + file + '" alt="Shelf Image" width="100" height="100" onclick="openImg(' + fotoId++ + ')"></img></div></div>');  });
```

as you can see, on the event "onClick" `onclick="openImg(' + fotoId++ + ')"`, i call the openImg function:

```
function openImg(id) {
var url = $('#img' + id).attr("src");};
```

every thing works fine, but i need to define the JS function "openImg" as a function in `$scope` because then I can do many things such as httppost. How can I change my code in the way that my function is part of $scope and i can call it from the tag `<img>` ?

**UPDATED**
i have tried to use the way which has explained by Pengyy and here is my code:

```
              angular.forEach(resData, function(file) {

               var element = angular.element($('.shelfgallery'));
               element.html('<div class="responsive"><div class="gallery">' +'<img id="img' + fotoId + '" src="' + file + 
                       '" alt="Shelf Image" width="100" height="100" ng-click="openImg(' 
                       + fotoId++ + ')"></img>');
               $compile(element)($scope)

                });
```

Comment: Btw. Your approach is too much "jQueryish". I suggest using ng-repeat in the template instead of .appending each item to the DOM using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `ng-repeat` to generate html block dynamically.

```
<div class="responsive" ng-repeat="file of resData">
  <img id="img" src="file" ng-click="openImg(resData.fotoid)"></img> 
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can use `$compile` in controller to append html block with angularjs built-in directive, such as ng-click.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.name = 'test value';
    
    $scope.test = function() {
      var element = angular.element($('.shelfgallery'));
      element.append('<img id="img_11" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" ng-click="openImg()"></img>');
      $compile(element)($scope);
    };
    
    $scope.openImg = function() {
      var url = $('#img_11').attr("src");
      alert(url);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  <button ng-click="test()">Add</button>
  <div class="shelfgallery"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows  just the last image instead of all images, and when i click on that, it give the error: ReferenceError: scope is not defined
    at Child.$scope.openImg (app.js:156), i have updated my post with my solution and the error

Comment: @Majico So you choosed the second way, then use `append` will solve your first problem, check the code snippet again.

Comment: thanks but when i click the image, i have the error : ReferenceError: scope is not defined
    at Child.$scope.openImg (app.js:156)
How can I resolve this ?

Comment: @Majico let's chat here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142710/angularjs-compile

Answer (score 2):

In Angular, you can use ng-click attribute to trigger an event or function.

Provide your img element with the ng-click event in place of onclick event

```
<img ng-click="anyFunction()" src="" />
```

In your controller or JS, provide the function on the scope variable

```
$scope.anyFunction = function(){
 /// Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.forEach(resData, function(file) {
 $('.shelfgallery').append('<div class="responsive"><div 
      class="gallery">' + '<img id="img' + fotoId + '" src="' + file + 
      '" alt="Shelf Image" width="100" height="100" 
       ng-click="openImg(' + fotoId++ + ')"></img></div></div>');
  });
```

Use ng-click instead of onclick. And controller will be like

```
$scope.openImg = function(id) {
   var url = $('#img' + id).attr("src");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using AngularJS, I would suggest to rewrite this code the *Angular way*. It can be something like:

```
<div class="shelfgallery">
    <div class="responsive" ng-repeat="file in resData">
        <img ng-src="file.src" ng-click="openImg(file)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your openImg function may be:

```
$scope.openImg = function(file) {
    console.log(file); /* file contains the whole object you have clicked on */
}
```